# How can I use this BootStrap onscreen keyboard for multiple input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Here is the keyboard I'd like to use:

```
<div id='key1' class="container my-3" id='first'>
    <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3" role='group'>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '1';">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '2';">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid'). value + '3';">3</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '4';">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '5';">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 " onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '6';">6</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '7';">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '8';">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '9';">9</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-danger py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value.slice(0, -1);">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" onclick="document.getElementById('empid').value=document.getElementById('empid').value + '0';">0</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, right now, the inputs get directed to empid only. I'd like to be able to switch to another input field (id='input2') after 6 characters have been typed into empid.

I'm open to using jQuery/Javascript but have no experience with them. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change `data-target-input` to target your element `#input-id` or `.form-control`

i.e. `<div data-target-input="#my_input_id">` or `<div data-target-input=".my_input_class">`

```js
$('[data-toggle="keybrd"]').each(function(){
 var btn = $(this).find('.btn'), input = $($(this).data('target-input'));
 btn.on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).text();
  if(val=='Delete'){
   input.val(input.val().slice(0,-1));
  }else{
   input.val(input.val()+val);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm p-0 pt-3">
   <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" id="empid">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container my-3" id='first' data-toggle="keybrd" data-target-input="#empid">
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3" role='group'>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3">3</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3">6</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3">9</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-danger py-3 mr-3">Delete</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">0</button>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm p-0 pt-3">
   <input class="form-control form-control-lg my-input" type="text">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container my-3" id='second' data-toggle="keybrd" data-target-input=".my-input">
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3" role='group'>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3">3</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">5</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3">6</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">7</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">8</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3">9</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-danger py-3 mr-3">Delete</button>
  <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3">0</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do I would recommend against JQuery and consider using a simple Javascript framework like Vue to bind data to your inputs. If you are going to use Jquery I would do something like the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentInput = 0;
  var totalInputs = 2
  
  $('.number-input')[currentInput].focus();
  
  function nextInput(){
   console.log(`currentInput: ${currentInput}`);
   if(currentInput < totalInputs - 1){
      currentInput++;
     $('.number-input')[currentInput].focus();
     console.log(`newinput: ${currentInput}`);
    } else if(currentInput >= totalInputs -1){
      currentInput = 0;
     $('.number-input')[currentInput].focus();
     console.log(`newinput: ${currentInput}`);      
    }
  }
  $('.enter-input').click(nextInput);
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




  <div class='container'>

<div class='form-inputs row'>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class='input-group-prepend bg-primary p-2'>First</span>
    <input class='number-input' type='number'>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class='input-group-prepend bg-primary p-2'>Second</span>
    <input class='number-input' type='number'>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='key1' class="my-3" id='first'>
    <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3" role='group'>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >1</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >2</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >3</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >4</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >5</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >6</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >7</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >8</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >9</button>
     </div>
     <div class="row btn-group-lg mb-3">
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-danger py-3 mr-3" >Delete</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-primary py-3 mr-3" >0</button>
       <button type="button" class="col-sm btn btn-success py-3 mr-3 enter-input" >Enter</button>
    </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

JQuery can retrieve a collection of tags which can allow you to iterate over them. I gave a common class name to the number inputs I want to iterate over and use that class name to grab a list of the elements so I can simply call .focus on the element.